# How to show time reversal symmetry does not break in the tight binding Hamiltonian for the honeycomb lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, graphene, time-reversal-symmetry

The Hamiltonian of the  honeycomb lattice is 
$$
H=\sum_{k\sigma}t(k) a_{k\sigma}^\dagger b_{k\sigma}+h.c
$$
Where $t(-k)=t^*(k)$.

If we do a time reversal transformation(according the answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/is-time-reversal-symmetry-broken-in-conventional-superconductors) post): $a_{k\uparrow}\to a_{-k\downarrow}$, $a_{k\downarrow}\to -a_{-k\uparrow}, t(k)\to t(-k)$. We can show that the Hamiltonian is invariant.

On the other hand, if we recall that the time reversal operator for the spin-1/2 particles can be written as $\mathcal{T}=i\sigma_y K$, time reversal symmetry means the Hamiltonian commutes with the time reversal operator. This leads to $\sigma_y H \sigma_y =H^*$.

**My question is 1) How is $\sigma_y$ applied to $H$; can anyone show me how to do this calculation? 2) How can I combine these two view points, i.e. the transformation shown above and the commutation relation below?**

Another confusion is: Does linearly polarized light break time reversal symmetry?

If we represent homogenous linearly polarized light by a vector field $\vec{A}=A(\sin \Omega t,0)$, similarly to [this article](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.235108).

The Hamiltonian can be written as:
$$
H=\sum_{k\sigma}t(k-A) a_{k\sigma}^\dagger b_{k\sigma}+h.c
$$

Again if we do a time reversal transformation: $a_{k\uparrow}\to a_{-k\downarrow}$, $a_{k\downarrow}\to -a_{-k\uparrow}, t(k-A)\to t(-k+A)$. We can also show that the Hamiltonian is invariant.

However, if we represent the light by a vector potential $\vec{A}=A(\cos \Omega t,0)$, then a time reversal transformation leads to $t(k-A)\to t(-k-A)$.  The Hamiltonian seems not time-reversal invariant. **How to solve this contradiction, since from a physical point of view, linearized light has no angular momentum, thus should not break time-reversal symmetry.**

Comment: How is your $w(k)$ related to $t(k)$?

Comment: @EverettYou They are same, I've corrected the typos